# Read UDP port telemetry using python

Tags: python, udp

How can I read data from Assetto Corsas telemetry UDP port (9996) from a remote computer and print it in python?

I've tried reading using sockets but I dont think this is possible as my code will not bind, im assuming because its occupied?

```
import socket
server = socket.socket() 
server.bind(("192.166.1.96", 9996)) 
server.listen(4) 
client_socket, client_address = server.accept()
print(client_address, "has connected")
while True:
    recvieved_data = client_socket.recv(1024)
    print(recvieved_data)
```

Comment: This code makes no sense for me: 1) you seem to bind to the remote IP of the device which you expect to send data instead of the local IP where you want to receive data - that's why it fails. 2) You also use TCP even if you say that device uses UDP. It is not fully clear how the device works, but for a remote UDP sender you need to configure at the remote sender where it should send the data too (i.e. your local IP and port) and then bind a UDP (not TCP) socket to this local IP and port and just call recv on the socket.